# facing an issue with haproxy / nginx

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I need to setup a reverse proxy server which would distribute traffic to the backend servers based on the incoming HOST header.

I opted for HAproxy for this but after setting up everything I realized that HAproxy reads the configuration just once when the service starts and continues to use the backend IP address unless it has been reloaded/restarted.
This is an issue for me since in my case if the backend server reboots it will have a different IP address and I dont have control on which IP address it gets.

I am thinking of moving to nginx server but before I go through all the setup I would like to know if we have the same issue with Nginx or not?
Meaning: If in the configuration file I have specific the name of backend server and if the related IP address changes, will Nginx refresh its dns cache to identify the new IP address?

(When the backend server changes IP, it is automatically updated in the hosts file of proxy server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nginx will do the job. See 'resolve' option here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server